# problemas con where en instruccion update

Tags: mysql, update

Tengo problemas con el update en Mysql worckbench 8.0.15 debido a que en una base de datos tengo creado un procedimiento almacenado para actualizar el valor especifico de un registro, la instruccion que ejecuta es un update delimitado con un where pero omite el where en cuestion y afecta a todos los registros de la tabla aqui esta el procedimiento almacenado.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `actVendedor` (id varchar(15), nombre varchar(15))

BEGIN

    update Vendedores set NombreVendedor = nombre
    where IDVendedor = id ;
END

call actVendedor ("V-001", "juan");
```

Comment: El IDvendedor en tu tabla de qué tipo es?

Comment: varcha r, intente con un tipo int pero me resulto igual

Answer (score 1):

A los valores de tu procedimiento almacenado les hace falta indicarles si son valores de entrada o salida, por lo cual para este caso deberías usar `IN` de este modo

Además deberías usar la sintaxis de `DELIMITER` para indicar donde terminará la creación de tu SP

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE PROCEDURE `actVendedor` (IN id varchar(15), IN nombre varchar(15))
BEGIN
  UPDATE Vendedores SET NombreVendedor = nombre
  WHERE IDVendedor = id;
END;
```

Posterior ya pùedes invocar a tu procedimiento almacenado del modo siguiente

```
CALL actVendedor("V-001", "juan");
```

Comment: correcto amigo, muchas gracias